# Is there a limit to read a table array as range in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

newbie in vba macro here, I am trying to play around with the vba code i found in the link attached below but it is not working when i have a huge range

I have a vba function that works on a say range C16000:C16954 but not range C116000:C116954, although they read the same number of rows

```
    FuzzyvLookup(B2,D16000:D16954,1) = "SOME VALUE" 
    FuzzyvLookup(B2,D116000:D116954,1) = #N/A when i expect it to be 
    FuzzyvLookup(B2,D116000:D116954,1) = "SOME VALUE"
```

Any suggestions on why so?

Added the link to the macro code I was referring to: (it is really long so i didn't paste it here!)
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.195635/

Comment: what excel version do you have? how are you exactly calling the function? What are you doing with the function return? What error do you get?

Comment: For starters, change all the instances of `Integer` to `Long`. Using `Integer` is bad practice here.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz hi, im using excel 2016, im using the function as such FuzzyvLookup(B2,D16000:D16954,1), comparing a value vs a column/range of values to see the closest match. 

It seems like it is a value not available error

Comment: @BigBen hi, why is it a bad practice? will change the instances! thank you for the tip

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) why - but that code is like 14 years old so maybe the developer gets a pass.

Comment: That code would fail with any range on rows >=32767.  So even back then only half the sheet was accessable!  So yes, change _all_ uses of `Integer`to `Long`

Comment: ^ In other words, no pass for the original developer :-).

Comment: @BigBen hi thank you for the knowledge! very useful for my future codes :)

Comment: @chrisneilsen hi, oh no, do you know why is that the case?  also , do you have any suggestions for me to tackle this problem? cos i have 169548 active rows now

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) for the limits of `Integer`, which are `-32,768 to 32,767`. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Literally do a find/replace on `Integer`, changing to `Long`.

Comment: @BigBen I just tested the function again after changing to long, it works! thank you!!!

Comment: @chrisneilsen thank you for helping also! it's really effective :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
Function FuzzyvLookup(myRange As range, strLookup As String, lookupType)

    ' lookup type
    ' 1 first
    ' 2 mid
    ' 3 last
    ' 0 all

    Dim a() As Long
    myRow = 2
    myCol = 2
    ReDim a(myRow - 1, myCol - 1) As Long
    a(0, 0) = 9
    a(1, 0) = 6
    a(0, 1) = 9
    a(1, 1) = 6
    Dim myVal
    myVal = ""
    For b = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
        If lookupType = 1 And myRange.Item(b, 1) Like strLookup & "*?" Then
            myVal = myRange.Item(b, 2)
            Exit For
        End If
        If lookupType = 2 And myRange.Item(b, 1) Like "?*" & strLookup & "*?" Then
            myVal = myRange.Item(b, 2)
            Exit For
        End If
        If lookupType = 3 And myRange.Item(b, 1) Like "?*" & strLookup Then
            myVal = myRange.Item(b, 2)
            Exit For
        End If
        If lookupType = 0 And myRange.Item(b, 1) Like "*" & strLookup & "*" Then
            myVal = myRange.Item(b, 2)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next b
    FuzzyvLookup= myVal
End Function
```

in your cell can test this macro:

```
Macro1(D16000:D16954, B2, 1)
```

remark: 1 mean first (begin from character 1 of the string)